# Get the line number of the caret in NSTextView

Tags: cocoa, nstextview, caret

I'm looking for a way to get the coordinates of the caret in the NSTextView using plain Cocoa.

I know how to do that in Windows, but Apple/Cocoa is completely new beast for me.

Thank you.

Comment: It's not clear what lines you want to count (i.e counting only the newline characters or the hard line wraps as well). In any case you may want to have a look at the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TextLayout/Tasks/CountLines.html).

Comment: @Nickkk, I am trying to get a position (x, y) of the caret inside the NSTextView. So the line number and the position inside the line where the caret is located. Keep in mind that current caret position may not be at the end of the text as I can click anywhere inside the view. The "y" position should account for line wraps, so that if the view has  characters wide and I keep typing without pressing Enter, symbol 12 will be on the line 2.

Comment: I don't understand "if the view has characters wide and I keep typing without pressing Enter, symbol 12 will be on the line 2.".

Comment: @Willeke, Oops, sorry. That's the numlock. Should be "if the view has 10 characters wide and I keep typing without pressing Enter, symbol 12 will be on the line 2". Any idea how to get both X and Y?