# Get the caret position (x, y) from NSTextView

Tags: macos, cocoa

The NSTextView will send [`-textViewDidChangeSelection:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstextviewdelegate/1449363-textviewdidchangeselection?language=objc) when the selection changes.

How do I get the caret line and position inside this notification?

TIA!!

EDIT:

Here is my code:

```
        NSRange selectedRange = [self selectedRange];
        NSRange newRange = [[self layoutManager] glyphRangeForCharacterRange:selectedRange actualCharacterRange:NULL];
        NSRect rect = [[self layoutManager] boundingRectForGlyphRange:newRange inTextContainer:[self textContainer]];
        NSInteger insertionPoint = [[[self selectedRanges] objectAtIndex:0] rangeValue].location;
```

And those are the values from lldb (when I click on line 3 position 3 of the text control):

```
Target 0: (text) stopped.
(lldb) p selectedRange
(NSRange) $0 = location=65, length=0
(lldb) p newRange
(NSRange) $1 = location=65, length=0
(lldb) p rect
(NSRect) $2 = (origin = (x = 60.73876953125, y = 32), size = (width = 0, height = 16))
(lldb) p insertionPoint
(NSInteger) $3 = 65
(lldb)
```

Now, line 3 is actually a big line 1 with couple of soft "carriage return" symbols inserted. Meaning that I didn't press Enter - line was wrapped at the end.

Oh, and what I expect to get is (3,3 - line 3, position 3) instead of (65 - position relative to the beginning of the text).

EDIT1:

I tried to put the code you provided in the handler and run the test program I have.

I got the wrong results - please see the screenshot.

[image]

I was expecting to have the following:

```
x = 3 and y = 3
```

Now if from here I press an "UP ARROW" key, I will get:

```
Cursor position changes. New position: x - 4, y - 1
```

which bring both numbers to be incorrect, because x position shouldn't be changing.

I'm trying to place this inside the

```
- (void)textViewDidChangeSelection:(NSNotification *)aNotification
```

Comment: Is the question how to get the text view from the notification or how to get the caret line and position from the text view?

Comment: Do you want to get a line number and character number or coordinates in the view?

Comment: @willeke, the question is - how to get the line number and a character position of the caret in the selection change notification. Thx.

Comment: See [Get Current Keyboard Cursor Location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19432454/get-current-keyboard-cursor-location)

Comment: @Willeke, I tried to implement the solution in the very first answer to that question but it doesn't work. I'm getting some weird numbers.

Comment: Post your code in the question please. And the numbers you get and expect.

Comment: @Willeke, code, result of the run and expectation are added to the OP. Thx.

Comment: is this the same question: [Get the line number of the caret in NSTextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39515246/get-the-line-number-of-the-caret-in-nstextview)? I'll try to find an answer this time, not the coordinates but the line number and character number in the line.

Comment: @Willeke, yes, it was, except there i was interested in the line number only.. I should probably delete that one and keep this one...

Answer (score 0):

`NSLayoutManager`'s method `lineFragmentRectForGlyphAtIndex:effectiveRange:` returns the rectangle for the line fragment where the glyph lies and (optionally), by reference, the entire range of glyphs in that fragment. With the range of glyphs on the line it is possible to calculate the character index on the line. The line index can be calculated by repeatedly calling this method for a glyph on the previous line. When the insertion point is at the end of the text then there is no glyph so the last glyph is used and the line and character index are adjusted.

```
NSUInteger lineNr = 0;
NSUInteger characterNr = 0;
BOOL extraCharacter = NO;
if (textView.textStorage.length > 0) {
    NSUInteger characterIndex = [textView selectedRange].location; // character index in text
    if (characterIndex >= textView.textStorage.length) {
         //  there is no glyph after the insertion point, use the last glyph and add a character later
        characterIndex--;
        extraCharacter = YES;
    }
    NSLayoutManager *layoutManager = textView.layoutManager;
    NSUInteger glyphIndex = [layoutManager glyphIndexForCharacterAtIndex:characterIndex];
    NSRange effectiveRange;
    NSRect lineRect = [layoutManager lineFragmentRectForGlyphAtIndex:glyphIndex effectiveRange:&effectiveRange];
    // effectiveRange is the glyph range of the line
    NSUInteger lineStart = [layoutManager characterIndexForGlyphAtIndex:effectiveRange.location];
    characterNr = characterIndex - lineStart;
    if (extraCharacter) {
        // extraLineFragmentRect is not equal to NSZeroRect if the last character in the text causes a line or paragraph break
        if (NSEqualRects(layoutManager.extraLineFragmentRect, NSZeroRect)) {
            characterNr++;
        }
        else {
            characterNr = 0;
            lineNr++;
        }
    }
    // count lines until effectiveRange is at the start of the text
    while (effectiveRange.location > 0 && effectiveRange.location != NSNotFound) {
        lineNr++;
        glyphIndex = effectiveRange.location - 1;
        lineRect = [layoutManager lineFragmentRectForGlyphAtIndex:glyphIndex effectiveRange:&effectiveRange];
    }
}
NSLog(@"Line: %li, character: %li", (long)lineNr, (long)characterNr);
```

Comment: I tried to test your code but the test failed. Please see the second edit of the OP. Thx.

Comment: @Igor The first line is y = 0, if you want to start at 1 then start `lineNr` at 1. x = 3 and 4 looks ok to me, "and" is 3 characters and "(on " is 4.

Comment: there is no line 0. The first line is always 1. . Now for the x coordinate - if I press "UP ARROW" key it shouldn't change. It should if I press "LEFT/RIGHT ARROW" keys or with the typing

Comment: The code is this answer calculates the line and character position. It doesn't change what `NSTextView` does with the the arrow keys. The up arrow moves the insertion point up to the same x coordinate, not the same character index.

Comment: I understand it doesn't change the behavior. What I'm saying is that if my cursor is on line 5, symbol 3 and I press either UP or DOWN arrow, then the correct position should be calculated as line 4/6, symbol 5. Only line number should change. And if I press LEFT or RIGHT ARROW, then only position will be changing and not line number. That's  how all text editor works and its logical. That's how MS Word, WordPad, NotePad, TextEdit and OpenOffice behaves.

Comment: My Textedit and Pages don't behave like that. How the arrow keys work is irrelevant for this question and answer. If you want to change this behaviour then ask a new question. please.